# Is it valid for different action creators to dispatch the same action or bad practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is it valid to do this:

```
export const nextUser = () => {
  // calculation here
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_USER',
    payload: userObject
  };
};

export const prevUser = () => {
  // calculation here
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_USER',
    payload: userObject
  };
};
```

Here I have two action creators, which do very similar operations. Both update a user object, but one is going forward, the other one backward. Is it valid to have them both dispatch the same action? In the end, the reducer would receive a user object and update, so it wouldn't have to know about whether we are going to the next or previous User. Or is this considered unclean, since my action creator is named differently than my reducer?

Comment: It seems fine and the differs which person you ask, but consider debugging your actions: What do you expect? Would you mind if everything is a "UPDATE_USER" action? Maybe "UPDATE_USER_NEXT" and "UPDATE_USER_PREVIOUS" is more suitable but that's just a matter of taste. So go ahead why not!

Answer (score 0):

Technically no problems, but...

> Here I have two action creators, which do very similar operations

Not similar but the exact operation.

> Both update a user object

These are just action creators, they represent an `action` they don't really "do" anything.
The unit that computes the next state is (and should be) the `reducer`, and if the reducer doesn't care about if its a `prevUser` or a `nextUser` then i don't see any reason to have 2 identical actions with different names (same `type` and `payload`).

**Edit**

I just noticed the `// calculation here` comment in your code, if that means you are doing some side effects, then indeed the place to compute the next state is inside the action creator / middle-wares (reducers should be pure).

Answer (score 0):

If you pass or dispatch those actions to the different reducer no problem. but if you dispatch those actions to same reducer, that reducer can not detect which of this actions occurred, because the type of two actions is the same. both type is 'UPDATE_USER'.

you can use this  approach:

```
export const nextUser = (userObject) => {
  // calculation here
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_USER',
    payload: {
              userType: "NEXT_USER"
              userData: userObject
             }
  };
};

export const prevUser = (userObject) => {
  // calculation here
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_USER',
    payload: {
              userType: "PREV_USER"
              userData: userObject
             }
  };
};
```

and handle those situation in reducer function by userType.